# Creating a trigger that inserts to a table and executes a batch file

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm creating a trigger that would run when a specific row is inserted into `TableName` AND if it hasn't run yet for the day. To achieve this, what we thought of was to include an insert statement in the trigger that would insert the current date into the `LOG` table, which should prevent it from running the rest of the day. After this, it would run a batchfile which would do its own thing.

The problem we're having is that the trigger doesn't insert anything in the `LOG` table, and it just reruns itself perpetually, including the batchfile.

Here's our Trigger:

```
USE [Database]
GO

DROP TRIGGER [schema].[TriggerName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [schema].[TriggerName]
   ON  [schema].[TableName]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if exists(select * from inserted where Column1 = 'Priority' and STATUS = 'F' )
BEGIN
    if not exists(select * from Database.Schema.Logs where [Date] = convert(date,getdate()))
    BEGIN
        --insert to logs table where [Date] default is [Date] = convert(date,getdate())
        BEGIN
            insert into Database.Schema.Logs(status) values ('Trigger is running')
        END
        -- Execute Procedure
        BEGIN
            EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"Procedure.bat"' 
        END
    END
END

GO
```

Comment: Having a trigger that uses `xp_cmdshell` sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: What larnu wrote. An alternative approach is to use service broker in an asynchronous manner as discussed [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Service-Broker-Sample-9c8f4730). And note that enabling xp_cmdshell is a security risk for your system in general. And give some serious reconsideration to using this table-based approach generally.

Comment: A trigger is executed **inside the context and transaction** of the statement that caused it to be fired. It should be **very nimble, very small, very fast** - do **NOT** do any "heavy lifting" or time-consuming tasks inside a trigger! (since the original statement will have to wait until the trigger is finished).

Comment: @Larnu can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @SMor I will try that thanks. I've been reading the things on the page that you linked and am excited to try this API if I get the permissions for it. Could you elaborate on why I shouldn't have xp_cmdshell though? If it's such as security risk why is it still in SQL?

Comment: @marc_s thanks for that! I was wondering why inserts sometimes run long. I think the Service Broker thing should handle that problem.

Comment: Triggers should be as *minimal* as possible, @MartianMarcera . Anything that happens in a trigger happens inside the same transaction that the DML statement is performed in, and that DML statement **cannot** complete until the trigger completes. `xp_cmdshell` is a `sysadmin` only function (unless you've configured the credentials for others to use it) and is expensive; you're running a `bat` file here so I have no idea what it's doing. This means that any DML statement has to wait for that `bat` file to be completely run, *successfully*. Also if the trigger fails, so too does the DML statement

Comment: @Larnu any idea why the trigger should fail in our code however? And why even after several times of itself being re-run, it still hasn't inserted anything in the logs table? I understand you're trying to stop me from using what is essentially an unacceptable code but I would still like to know why it fails in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are inserting a [Date] value into the Logs table (or there is a default for the [Date] column). Every time the trigger fires (and there is no entry for the current date) a new entry is created but with NULL date...and this keeps going on forever.

```
create table dbo.TableNameTest
(
Column1 varchar(200),
Status char(1),
CreatedOn datetime default(getdate())
);

create table dbo.LogsTest
(
Status varchar(50),
[Date] date default(getdate())
)
go

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_ins_upd_TableNameTest on dbo.TableNameTest
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --no inserted rows...
    if not exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        --...return
        return;
    end

    --no eligible inserted/updated rows..
    if not exists(select * from inserted where Column1 = 'Priority' and STATUS = 'F')
    begin
        --..return
        return
    end

    --bat already executed for the day
    if exists (select * from dbo.LogsTest where [Date] = convert(date,getdate()))
    begin
        return
    end

    --there is a concurrency issue here..
    --if the bat execution takes a long time...the trigger could fire the bat twice
    --maybe insert processing log status and delete the log if cmdshell is not successful ??

    declare @res int;
    --at this point..execute the bat
    print 'bat is going to be executed from within the trigger';

    EXEC @res=master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\testnew\whoamii.bat', no_output ;

    if @res = 0
    begin
        insert into dbo.LogsTest(Status, [Date]) values('Trigger executed the bat', getdate())
    end

END
go




insert into dbo.TableNameTest (Column1, Status) values ('random', 'R') --bat not executed
insert into dbo.TableNameTest (Column1, Status) values ('Priority', 'F') --bat not executed
go

--2nd time
insert into dbo.TableNameTest (Column1, Status) values ('random', 'R') --bat not executed
insert into dbo.TableNameTest (Column1, Status) values ('Priority', 'F') --bat not executed
go

select *
from dbo.TableNameTest;

select *
from dbo.LogsTest 
go


--cleanup
drop table dbo.TableNameTest;
drop table dbo.LogsTest
go
```

Comment: yes I'm sure that whenever we insert a row in the logs table, it's default is the current date. It's also in the code I added. --insert to logs table where [Date] default is [Date] = convert(date,getdate()). The problem is that it doesn't insert when the trigger runs. I will however try your approach.